# possible misunderstanding of map iterators with for loops

Tags: c++, dictionary

very specific question I'm afraid (and I'm rather a novice, so apologies in advance):

I'm currently trying to finish my final project for a University object-oriented C++ course. I'm creating a student database to store exam results for students. My setup has loads of custom classes but all work perfectly (or at least do what I want them to do).

The project is set up as follows:

I have a "master" map of all "course"s, to which everything points to (so a course isn't duplicated if more than one student is taking it).

A "student" is a vector of pointers to "course"s and a corresponding double "result", and I have a master map of all students in the system.

a "degree" is a class of two vectors of pointers, one to courses offered by that degree, and one to students taking that degree. When a degree is created, it searches both master maps. If the first x letters in a course id matches the degree prefix, the course is added. If a student's subject matches the course name, the student is added.

My problem is this:

As I have some options to manually input courses and students after the initial setup from CSV files, I have writen a function to update my degrees if a course/result is added which should be included in a degree (see below). However, this code inevitably results in the first course and student being re-added (i.e. repeated) to the first degree the first time this function is called. this problem is not repeated if the function is called again. I have absolutely no idea why. A huge amount of time and cout statements later and I'm no closer to solving this. Am I missing something obvious about the first run? I may have set the loops up wrong (I'm not very familiar with maps). Don't hesitate to call me an idiot!

As I have said above, all the rest of the program is gravy, without this odd issue the program is fine. The problem does not appear to come from my print functions either.

Thank you in advance for your time.

```
//upgrade degrees function: used whenever new courses or students could be created by the user. It ticks through all stored degrees and scans cd and sd. If it finds an unstored course or student that should be stored, they are added.

void degree_database::update_degrees(course_database &cd, student_database &sd) {
    cout << "updating degrees..." << endl;

    bool found = false;
    vector<degree>::iterator current;
    for (current = start; current < end; ++current) {

            //scan course list
        map<string, course>::iterator x;
        for (x = cd.get_start(); x != cd.get_end(); ++x) {
            if (x->first.substr(0,3) == current->get_prefix().substr(0,3) || current->get_prefix() == "ALL") {

                //check to see if course is already stored
                vector<course*>::iterator a;
                for (a = current->get_c_start(); a < current->get_c_end(); ++a) {
                    if (*a == &(x->second)) {
                        found = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }

                //if found == true, then while loop broke early (i.e. the course was already stored).
                if (found == false) current->add_course(x->second);
                found = false;
            }
        }

        //scan student list
        found = false;
        map<string, student>::iterator y;
        for (y = sd.get_start(); y != sd.get_end(); ++y) {
            if (y->second.get_subject() == current->get_name() || current->get_name() == "All") {

                //check to see if course is already stored
                vector<student*>::iterator b;
                for (b = current->get_s_start(); b < current->get_s_end(); ++b) {
                    if (*b == &(y->second)) {
                        found = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }

                //if found == true, then while loop broke early (i.e. the student was already stored).
                if (found == false) current->add_student(y->second);
                found = false;
            }
        }

    }

    cout << "done." << endl; 
}
```

Comment: `for (current = start; current < end; ++current)` -- how do you get values of `start` and `end`?

Comment: sorry: they are simply start = degree_list.begin(), end = degree_list.end(), where degree_list is the name of my vector<degree>. I only rename them in the degree_database class out of sheer stubbornness. The same is true for c_start, c_end, s_start and s_end.

Comment: can you pls also show how you have implemented `cd.get_start()` and `cd.get_end()`?

Comment: same thing again: cd.start is a map<string, course>::iterator with a value of course_list.begin(). cd.end = course_list.end(). get_cd_start() and get_cd_end() return their values. I started using this system at the beginning of this project (a long time ago in my c++ understanding) because I thought it would be easier to share .begin() and .end() with non-member/non-friend functions and have carried it on for the rest of the project because reasons.

Comment: `current->get_name() == "All"` -- I am guessing you are comparing strings, and `get_name()` returns `string`. If yes, pls use `strcmp` http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcmp/ Same thing applies for other string comparison you have.

Comment: right cheers, will do. Could this have caused the odd repeat I described? I can't really see how.

Comment: `(*b == &(y->second))` Did you define `==` operator for your classes (`course` and `student`)?

Comment: This should be comparing addresses, not classes? If I understand it correctly, the pointer from degree to student/course should be the same as the address of student/course.

Comment: yes, you are right...i did not look at the code carefully, before writing the comment..sorry.

Comment: You should get in the habit of *always* using `!= end` in iterator loops. If you use `< end` as I see you do you might use that on a collection that does not provide iterators with meaningful less-than operators. A map or list iterator that happened to be just a pointer might compare less or greater than end depending on where in memory the allocator put the nodes.

Comment: How is `degree.add_course()` implemented? By the way, `current` is not reinitialized before the second loop and may be `end()`.

Answer (score 0):

You store `course` by value in the course list and then you use *pointer* to this object in comparison. Apparently, you shoud store pointers in the map. I think `(*a == &(x->second))`  fails on the first run and pointer to the object from the course map is added to a `degree` object. On the second run, `(*a == &(x->second))` succeeds and all looks ok. The same for `student` map.

Comment: hmmm... if this were true shouldn't all the courses and students be duplicated? At the moment only one of each from a large list are re-added. I'm not sure if using pointers in my base map is the way to go, as my `map<string, course>` is the only place where the courses are stored.

Comment: could you post complete source code? it would be much easier to help.